# Spacing of rows in a table

Tags: tables, spacing

I am using package `tabular` but encounter a problem with the spacing of rows, I would like to have more space at the top and at the bottom of each formula. I already looked at older posts dealing with this issue and they suggested to use `arraystretch` but it stretches all the rows (I don't want first row to be stretched for example) but most importantly **unequally** (there is more space at the top than at the bottom).

This is what my table currently looks like:
[image]

This is what `arraystretch` (with factor 3) do to it:

[image]

In both cases it is not aesthetically pleasing. And I can't seem to find any simple solution to my problem.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
Nom de la méthode & Formule de majoration de l'erreur & Ordre de convergence \\ 
\hline 
Rectangles à gauche & $|E_h^{RG}(f)| \leq \dfrac{h}{2} (\beta-\alpha)\lVert f'\rVert_{\infty}^{[a,b]}$ & 1 \\ 
\hline
Point Milieu &  $|E_h^{PM}(f)| \leq \dfrac{h^2}{24} (\beta-\alpha)\lVert f^{(2)}\rVert_{\infty}^{[a,b]}$ & 2 \\ 
\hline 
Trapèzes & $|E_h^T(f)| \leq \dfrac{h^2}{12} (\beta-\alpha)\lVert f^{(2)}\rVert_{\infty}^{[a,b]}$ & 2 \\ 
\hline 
Simpson & $|E_h^S(f)| \leq \dfrac{h^4}{2880} (\beta-\alpha)\lVert f^{(4)}\rVert_{\infty}^{[a,b]}$ & 4 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding `\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{6pt}` to the preamble and `\makegapedcells` beofr your `tabular` should help. You can of course adjust the amount to of added space to your needs.

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful and simple, it works as intended.

Comment: The suggested duplicate - [Column and row padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764) - contains reference to [`cellspace`](//ctan.org/pkg/cellspace) that is covered in the currently-accepted answer.

Comment: @Werner I'm sorry I made a duplicate, I was lost in the huge amount of answers. Thank you for the linked post and the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool for that is `cellspace`, which defines a minimal vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter`S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`, or any letter you please with loadtime option `[column=…]`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{cellspace} 
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{6pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{6pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|Sc|Sc|Sc|}
\hline
Nom de la méthode & Formule de majoration de l'erreur & Ordre de convergence \\
\hline
Rectangles à gauche & $|E_h^{RG}(f)| \leq \dfrac{h}{2} (\beta-\alpha)\lVert f'\rVert_{\infty}^{[a,b]}$ & 1 \\
\hline
Point Milieu & $|E_h^{PM}(f)| \leq \dfrac{h^2}{24} (\beta-\alpha)\lVert f^{(2)}\rVert_{\infty}^{[a,b]}$ & 2 \\
\hline
Trapèzes & $|E_h^T(f)| \leq \dfrac{h^2}{12} (\beta-\alpha)\lVert f^{(2)}\rVert_{\infty}^{[a,b]}$ & 2 \\
\hline
Simpson & $|E_h^S(f)| \leq \dfrac{h^4}{2880} (\beta-\alpha)\lVert f^{(4)}\rVert_{\infty}^{[a,b]}$ & 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is concise and clear. This answer is very useful (+1)

Answer (score 4):

The most elegant typographic approach to keep stuff from getting too close to horizontal lines in a table? Easy: Don't use horizontal lines!

Here's a `tabularx`-based implementation of this idea.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X} $ centered version of 'X' col. type
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$\displaystyle}l<{$}} % automatic math mode

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l >{$\displaystyle}l<{$} C @{}}
\toprule
Nom de la méthode & $Formule de majoration de l'erreur$ & Ordre de convergence \\ 
\midrule 
Rectangles à gauche & 
   \abs{E_h^{\mathit{RG}}(f)} \le \frac{h}{2}    (\beta-\alpha) \norm[\big]{f'}_{\infty}^{[a,b]}      & 1 \\ 
\addlinespace
Point Milieu &  
   \abs{E_h^{\mathit{PM}}(f)} \le \frac{h^2}{24} (\beta-\alpha) \norm[\big]{f^{(2)}}_{\infty}^{[a,b]} & 2 \\ 
\addlinespace 
Trapèzes & 
   \abs{E_h^T(f)} \le \frac{h^2}{12}   (\beta-\alpha) \norm[\big]{f^{(2)}} _{\infty}^{[a,b]}          & 2 \\ 
\addlinespace 
Simpson & 
   \abs{E_h^S(f)} \le \frac{h^4}{2880} (\beta-\alpha) \norm[\big]{f^{(4)}} _{\infty}^{[a,b]}          & 4 \\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabularx} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not was I was originally looking for, but thank you for the extra explanations, that's instructive and helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Here are three possibilities using `makecell`, `nicematrix` or `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%%% first example %%%
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{4pt}

%%% second example %%%
\usepackage{nicematrix}

%%% third example %%%
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
Nom de la méthode & Formule de majoration de l'erreur & Ordre de convergence \\ 
\hline 
Rectangles à gauche & $|E_h^{RG}(f)| \leq \dfrac{h}{2} (\beta-\alpha)\lVert f'\rVert_{\infty}^{[a,b]}$ & 1 \\ 
\hline
Point Milieu &  $|E_h^{PM}(f)| \leq \dfrac{h^2}{24} (\beta-\alpha)\lVert f^{(2)}\rVert_{\infty}^{[a,b]}$ & 2 \\ 
\hline 
Trapèzes & $|E_h^T(f)| \leq \dfrac{h^2}{12} (\beta-\alpha)\lVert f^{(2)}\rVert_{\infty}^{[a,b]}$ & 2 \\ 
\hline 
Simpson & $|E_h^S(f)| \leq \dfrac{h^4}{2880} (\beta-\alpha)\lVert f^{(4)}\rVert_{\infty}^{[a,b]}$ & 4 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{center}


\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines, cell-space-limits=4pt]{ccc}
Nom de la méthode & Formule de majoration de l'erreur & Ordre de convergence \\ 
Rectangles à gauche & $|E_h^{RG}(f)| \leq \dfrac{h}{2} (\beta-\alpha)\lVert f'\rVert_{\infty}^{[a,b]}$ & 1 \\ 
Point Milieu &  $|E_h^{PM}(f)| \leq \dfrac{h^2}{24} (\beta-\alpha)\lVert f^{(2)}\rVert_{\infty}^{[a,b]}$ & 2 \\ 
Trapèzes & $|E_h^T(f)| \leq \dfrac{h^2}{12} (\beta-\alpha)\lVert f^{(2)}\rVert_{\infty}^{[a,b]}$ & 2 \\ 
Simpson & $|E_h^S(f)| \leq \dfrac{h^4}{2880} (\beta-\alpha)\lVert f^{(4)}\rVert_{\infty}^{[a,b]}$ & 4 \\  
\end{NiceTabular} 
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\SetTblrInner{rowsep=4pt}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={ccc}, hlines, vlines}
Nom de la méthode & Formule de majoration de l'erreur & Ordre de convergence \\ 
Rectangles à gauche & $|E_h^{RG}(f)| \leq \dfrac{h}{2} (\beta-\alpha)\lVert f'\rVert_{\infty}^{[a,b]}$ & 1 \\ 
Point Milieu &  $|E_h^{PM}(f)| \leq \dfrac{h^2}{24} (\beta-\alpha)\lVert f^{(2)}\rVert_{\infty}^{[a,b]}$ & 2 \\ 
Trapèzes & $|E_h^T(f)| \leq \dfrac{h^2}{12} (\beta-\alpha)\lVert f^{(2)}\rVert_{\infty}^{[a,b]}$ & 2 \\ 
Simpson & $|E_h^S(f)| \leq \dfrac{h^4}{2880} (\beta-\alpha)\lVert f^{(4)}\rVert_{\infty}^{[a,b]}$ & 4 \\  
\end{tblr} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have trouble running ```nicematrix``` package for unknown reason. But the first method is very efficient, thank you!